# Defining and assigning roles per object in Django

Tags: python, permissions, roles, django-permissions, django-guardian

What could be a good way to define roles using [django-guardian](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)? I would like to set to a users groups of permissions over an object, and so that permissions can be added to the role and be accesible to all the users associated with a particular object.

Imagine that you are building a project-management app. A user can be either a project-manager or a developer. One user can participate in multiple Projects and have the role of a developer in some and be the project-manager in some others.

The idea is to define those roles that will allow to assign permissions over an object, a project in this case, in "batches" to a user, and also if a new permissions is added to a specific role, the role will be updated and the users will have available the new permission over all the objects where they have that role assigned.

The project I found that did something like this was [django-permissions](https://github.com/diefenbach/django-permissions/tree/master/permissions) which had something call Local Role, which is basically what I want to achieve with django-guardian. Sadly the package is very poorly documented and hasn't been updated in the last 4 years.